# Sum Values in Second Column where First Column Meets condition in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sum

I'm using google sheets to collaborate with others on an event. There are four columns in total:

```
Name,         Table No, N.Guests, Total on Table 
John Smith,          1        2             Y1
Andrew Smith,        1        3             Y2  
Michael Smith,       2        4             Y3
```

I'm looking for a way to sum over all the number of guests who are on the same table. I don't see how a simple if statement would do that. *Is a custom function required and how would I do this?*

If it were in python I would write a loop and have an if statement to check the table number and some over only those that meet the condition.

*Is there a way to do this with google sheets?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SUMIF` formula.

Picture data as follows (Cell A1 top left):

```
Name    TableNo    N.Guests   Total
John       1          3       =SUMIF(B$2:B$5, B2, C$2:C$5)
Fred       2          2
Mary       3          2
Susan      2          4
```

copy the formula down...

and voila.

The dollar signs are there to anchor the formula vertically so you can copy the range.